# Who is syntax.error and why is he deleting questions?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, deleted-accounts

I noticed on [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417928/how-to-determine-if-theres-a-duplicate-on-an-array) (10K+ only):

[image: Who is this mysterious user]

Who is this mysterious (non)user named *syntax.error*? And why is he deleting questions? I presume this is because the user no longer exists, but in that case it should at least say

> deleted by Community♦

Comment: He was probably a 10k user at one time, who has since been deleted.

Comment: @JoshC Since? In 8 hours? While this is _possible_, it, in all honesty, doesn't look _probable_.

Comment: I imagine its the name of the user who asked the question (who's account has since been deleted). The name of the user just doesn't get re-written to userXXXX on the *deleted by*, for some reason. It can't be a 10k user, as a 10k user doesn't have the ability to solo-delete a question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That was the user's name before their account was deleted. They deleted their own question, and then presumably their account shortly after. The deletion message is denormalized, so it captures the user's name at the time of generation and isn't modified by the user name anonymization process that happens on account deletion.

The [question history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20417928/revisions), which is generated live, correctly shows the subsequently anonymized user name with the deletion event.

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes sense. It was just the unfortunate username that made me think this was an SO bug.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Real languages (like what SO is written in) don't compile/throw exceptions on syntax errors.  They specifically don't pollute the output with weird error outputs /smugface